# How to remove a single client certificate?

Tags: certificates

Isn't it possible to remove a single client certificate from a device?

On a Galaxy S6 running 5.0.2 I can remove all client certificates using:

```
System settings
  Lock screen and security
    Other security settings
      Clear credentials
```

Or I can delete a single trusted CA certificate from:

```
System settings
  Lock screen and security
    Other security settings
      View security certificates
        User
```

However there seems to be no option to remove a single client (non-CA) certificate.

Comment: Same problem here. Android separates the certificates into two categories: certificates for "VPN and apps" and certificates for "Wi-Fi". While I can remove single "VPN and apps" certificates, I have to use the "Clear credentials" feature (which clears ALL user-installed certificates, both "VPN and apps" and "Wi-Fi") to remove a single "Wi-Fi" certificate. Very annoying. Just, why? PS: I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S9+ with Android 8.0.0.

Comment: It is indeed annoying, same on Magic UI 4.

Answer (score -1):

Just forget the wireless SSID the cert is for and it will delete the cert. I've verified this on Galaxy S7 running 8.0.0 and Note 8 running 8.0.0 as well.

Comment: The certificate is not for any SSID, the certificate is for TLS connections in general.